# How to set up pagination with no MySQL data

Tags: php, pagination

My task is to list data (product details) starting with the name of a folder and it's location on the server. MySQL is not used and its out of my hands unfortunately, which is causing a problem for me with pagination... any help will be very much appreciated.

Here's my code... which is ugly granted, but works perfectly... it's just that it will show all results as is!

```
<div style="width:750px;">
<?php

$ALL_PARTS = array();

// LOOP THROUGH MEMBERS RESOURCES ROOT FOLDER TO FIND ALL MEMBER RESOURCES FOLDERS

foreach (glob("root_folder/sub_folder/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $ROOT_FOLDERS_PATH) {

// WE CAN NOW FIND ALL RELEVANT FOLDERS CONTAINING THE DATA NEEDED

       foreach (glob("$ROOT_FOLDERS_PATH/offers/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH) {

           $FIXED_PRODUCT_CODE = file_get_contents("$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/fixed-product-code.txt", true);
           $PRODUCT_TITLE = file_get_contents("$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/product-title.txt", true);
           $PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = file_get_contents("$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/product-description.txt", true);

// WE NOW NEED TO RETURN THE PRODUCT IMAGE NAME WHICH IS IN ANOTHER LOCATION
// FIRST CREATE ARRAY OF ITEMS TO FILTER OUT IN RESULT

$ignore = Array(".", "..", "$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/assets/product_img/index.php", "$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/assets/product_img/.htaccess");

// GO GET THE IMAGE NAME AND PATH

foreach (glob("$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/assets/product_img/*") as $GET_IMAGE_NAME) {

// IF WE HAVE AN IMAGE AND PRODUCT CODE, DEFINE OPENING WRAPPER DIV AND THE IMAGE
// THEN DEFINE THE URL TO THE PRODUCT AND CLOSE THE WRAPPER DIV

     if((!in_array($GET_IMAGE_NAME, $ignore)) && (!empty($GET_IMAGE_NAME)) && (!empty($FIXED_PRODUCT_CODE)) ){

         $PART_1 = "<div style='width:355px; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:10px; float:left; height:130px;'>";
         $PART_2 = "<div style='float:left; height:150px; padding-right:10px;'><img src='" . $GET_IMAGE_NAME . "' width='100' alt='' /></div>";
         $PART_3 = "<div><a href='subscriber_offers.php?product=" . md5($FIXED_PRODUCT_CODE) ."'>" . $PRODUCT_TITLE ."</a><p>" . $PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION  . "</p></div>";
         $PART_4 = "</div>";

     }
}

// PUT DEFINED PARTS TOGETHER 

$ALL_PARTS[$PRODUCT_TITLE] = $PART_1 . $PART_2 . $PART_3 . $PART_4;

    }
}

ksort($ALL_PARTS);

foreach($ALL_PARTS as $PRODUCT){
echo $PRODUCT;
}
?>
</div>
```

This gives me a product listing in alphabetical order.

```
    ksort($ALL_PARTS);

    foreach($ALL_PARTS as $PRODUCT){
    echo $PRODUCT;
}
```

But how do I then have $arr contain all data of $ALL_PARTS array in such a way that can be accessed by pagination script?

The following will just give me the last iteration of the relevant loop... (obviously)

```
$arr = array($PRODUCT);
```

Comment: flat files instead of a db, that's the problem.

Comment: Yes Dagon, indeed... thanks for that ;)

Comment: instead of outputing each element, create array of the data then sort that array. Then loop over array to create html. Once in array you can get an array length also

Comment: don't you find USING ALL CAPS variable names slower to type? You either have to use caps lock and remember you did, or hold shift which reduces typing speed. Not to mention the effect on others reading your code.

Comment: @charliefl - thank you for your positive response... me thinks you can solve this... which is why you fail to make cocky remarks... any chance of an example of how to put your answer into action? Please?

Comment: well you're choosing to do it fundamentally WRONG in my opinion by not using a db. I agree with the general approach @charlietfl suggested. And the comments are just that, not answers.

Comment: @Dagon... lol... I'm wearing a green sweatshirt right now... any problem with that? Actually, I use all caps with PHP vars when I am working stuff out... all caps tells me which parts of my script are not finalized. Cheer up dude... there's no need to be so miserable you know! Did you just find out that Santa is not real?

Comment: @user1667105 - comments here about code style and readability are in general not meant as personal attacks. They are relevant because, when you seek assistance with your code, it is a good idea to make your questions/code as readable as possible. That means using lowercase_underscore or camelCase variables, and code indentation. It'll help you too!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a database? If you don't wish to (or can't) use MySQL, there's always SQLite3, which is essentially a data file that can be accessed and modified using SQL.

Comment: @halfer - first off, thank you for your comments... second, I'm clearly a new member. I don't feel that there is any need for arrogance or snotty attitudes, which were presented to me within seconds of posting my question in any circustances... but you know... it's not a very welcoming manner and spoils great sites like this one. Of course, you make sense and I shall take your advice on board - shame the tone of comments previous to yours were not so educational in intent :! Yep... the lack of mysql is out of my hands.

Comment: @user1667105 - StackOverflow is definitely a "sink or swim" environment. Sometimes comments that appear to be rather sharp are in fact just direct, and - odd as it may seem - the comments from Dagon and Tiberiu-Ionuț Stan were in fact helpful. Perhaps it is the slightly OCD characteristics of jaded programmers? `;)`. For clarification purposes you could edit your question to explain that MySQL is out of the question, rather than just that you are not using it. Again, can you use SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code to create sortable data array first, then use array to generate html:

```php
<?

// LOOP THROUGH MEMBERS RESOURCES ROOT FOLDER TO FIND ALL MEMBER RESOURCES FOLDERS


$data=array();

foreach (glob("root_folder/sub_folder/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $ROOT_FOLDERS_PATH) {

// WE CAN NOW FIND ALL RELEVANT FOLDERS CONTAINING THE DATA NEEDED

    foreach (glob("$ROOT_FOLDERS_PATH/offers/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH) {

        $FIXED_PRODUCT_CODE = file_get_contents("$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/fixed-product-code.txt", true);
        $PRODUCT_TITLE = file_get_contents("$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/product-title.txt", true);
        $PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = file_get_contents("$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/product-description.txt", true);

        // WE NOW NEED TO RETURN THE PRODUCT IMAGE NAME WHICH IS IN ANOTHER LOCATION
        // FIRST CREATE ARRAY OF ITEMS TO FILTER OUT IN RESULT

        $ignore = Array(".", "..", "$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/assets/product_img/index.php", "$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/assets/product_img/.htaccess");

        // GO GET THE IMAGE NAME AND PATH

        foreach (glob("$RESOURCE_FOLDERS_PATH/assets/product_img/*") as $GET_IMAGE_NAME) {

        // IF WE HAVE AN IMAGE AND PRODUCT CODE, DEFINE OPENING WRAPPER DIV AND THE IMAGE
        // THEN DEFINE THE URL TO THE PRODUCT AND CLOSE THE WRAPPER DIV

            if((!in_array($GET_IMAGE_NAME, $ignore)) && (!empty($GET_IMAGE_NAME)) && (!empty($FIXED_PRODUCT_CODE)) ){
                       /* push data to array*/
               $data[]=array( 'title'=> $PRODUCT_TITLE, 'descr'=> $PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION , 'img'=>$GET_IMAGE_NAME, 'code'=>md5($FIXED_PRODUCT_CODE));

            }
        }
    }
}

/* now sort array arbitrarily using "asort()"*/
asort( $data);

/* now create html */
$ALL_PARTS='';
foreach( $data as $row){

    $ALL_PARTS. = "<div style='width:355px; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:10px; float:left; height:130px;'>";
    $ALL_PARTS. = "<div style='float:left; height:150px; padding-right:10px;'><img src='" . $row['img'] . "' width='100' alt='' /></div>";
    $ALL_PARTS. = "<div><a href='subscriber_offers.php?product=" . $row['code'] ."'>" . $row['title'] ."</a><p>" . $row['descr']  . "</p></div>";
    $ALL_PARTS. = "</div>";

}
echo $ALL_PARTS;


?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I managed to create the array and use the product title as key. Using ksort this gives me a product listing in alphabetical order, but I'll study your example and improve my solution no doubt ;) So that's the sorting... now what to do about pagination from this point?

Comment: not sure what how you want to present pagination. Can use javascript to display it with all content on one page. Use a counter to insert wrapper elements, compare to `count($data)` for example

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks for you time, it's much appreciated. I'd rather not use client side for pagination - I don't like to see massive changes when JS is disabled. But thanks all the same.